# Android - File empty after crash

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am working on my game which saves user data in some files on the device. After the game crashes, the user does not retrieve these data. Immediately after the crash the corresponding file is empty. Furthermore, a backup file is created below to save new data to ensure that old data is not deleted. This backup file is also empty.

I don't understand how they could be empty.
You can find below the save function :

Algorithm form :

```
copy file to file_backup
if save data to file_temp then
    move file_temp to file
else 
    delete file_temp
```

C++ form :

```
const std::string path = "dataPlayer.dat";
const std::string backupPath = atPath + "_back";

if (PlatformInterface::fileExists(path))
{
    if (PlatformInterface::fileExists(backupPath))
       PlatformInterface::removeFile(backupPath);
    PlatformInterface::copyFile(path, backupPath);
}

const std::string tempPath = path + "_temp";
// Save in compact form.
XMLError error = dataDocument.SaveFile(tempPath.c_str(), true);
if (error != XML_NO_ERROR)
{
     PlatformInterface::removeFile(tempPath);
}
else
{
    bool moved = PlatformInterface::moveFile(tempPath, path);
    if (!moved)
    {
        PlatformInterface::removeFile(tempPath);
    }
}
```

If you have any idea I will thank you !

Edit : 
The PlatformInterface::copyFile(path, backupPath) method :

```
public static void copyFile(final String path, final String destination) {
    try {
        if (!new File(path).exists())
            return;
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The file seems to be correctly closed.

Comment: the important thing is: why it crashs and how to prevent this..

Comment: Crash may be due to an app error but it can be also due to device shutdown (low battery, critical device failure).

Answer (score 2):

Due to an unusual termination of the program, the buffer might not get flushed to the file.

In order to prevent this, flush the file after each write (close the stream or fclose the file descriptor) and reopen it using append.

From experience the ext file system (like the one from Android) uses the disk cache more then NTFS (it flushes later rather then sooner).

Comment: I post the copyFile function into my question. It seems the file is correctly closed after writing. Do you think it is ok like this ?

Comment: This looks like Java code, are you using JNI for the file transfer ? You are closing streams properly in Java - still no guarantee of flush on hdd . Try implementing copy file with stdio (fprintf and fscanf). Some questions regarding your app : Are you sure the path received by java is correct ? Do you get any exceptions ? Does your application crash during copy file ? Is the file you are copying empty ?

Comment: Yes, I am using JNI. (writing)

Comment: Yes, I am using JNI. I'm not sure the path is correctly received by java. There is no exception (crash is produced by removing battery). The file is not empty (check by USB). I am trying to use FileChannel::force(true), File::flush() and FileDescriptor::sync() methods.

Comment: Well, if you crash your application in mid process of copying, it's normal to have nothing , regardless of how you close your stream (is this what are you trying to achieve ? ). Check the java paths (a simple println should do it ) , just to be sure.